Взаимодействие из JS с функцией в PHP через JSON запрос
Задача. Нужно без обновления страницы вывести данные из базы данных в модальное окно, которое открывается при нажатии на кнопку. Для этого в JS я вызываю функцию PHP и передаю несколько параметров через JSON, затем также через JSON возвращаю массив с данными из таблицы базы данных.
let params = {
  userfunc: 'get_preview',
  modul: 'home',
  id: 1
};
let response = await fetch('./functions/functions.php', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(params),
});
if (response.ok) {
  let result = await response.json();
  console.log(result);
};

в PHP пишу следующий код
function get_preview($module, $id) {
  global $db;
  $result = $db -> prepare("SELECT * FROM $module WHERE `status` != '0'");
  $result->execute(array($id));
  $result = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY);
  echo json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$param = json_decode($_POST['params']);
$userfunc = $param['userfunc'];
$module = $param['modul'];
$id = $param['id'];
if ($userfunc == 'get_preview') {
 get_preview($module, $id);
}

Постоянно появляется ошибка JSON, помогите пожалуйста сделать код рабочим.

Что за ошибка? Какой JSON отправляется на бэк? Какой возвращается? В какой момент возникает и где ошибка? Добавьте эту информацию в сам вопрос

Вы определитесь, JSON или application/x-www-urlencoded (что бы использовать $_POST).
ИМХО, тут JSON совершенно не нужен.

Я так и не разобрался до конца в вопросе передачи параметров в PHP.  Alexey Ten если без JSON можно обойтись, то я только за такое решение. До этого в коде тоже пробовал через x-www-form-urlencoded, но ничего не работало, видимо где-то еще была ошибка.

Когда вы отправляете JSON, на стороне PHP нужно совершить некоторые нетривиальные действия что бы достать из него данные.
И в 99% случаев нет никакого смысла этим заморачиваться и можно просто отправить данные в стандартном формате application/x-www-urlencoded который PHP сам распарсит в глобальный массив $_POST.
let params = {
  userfunc: 'get_preview',
  modul: 'home',
  id: 1
};
let response = await fetch('./functions/functions.php', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: new URLSearchParams(params),
});
if (response.ok) {
  let result = await response.json();
  console.log(result);
};

function get_preview($module, $id) {
  // получаем данные из БД
  echo json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
if ($_POST['userfunc'] == 'get_preview') {
 get_preview($_POST['modul'], $_POST['id']);
}


Зачем уж такую явную инъекцию-то делать?

@Ипатьев функцию get_preview я не правил ¯_(ツ)_/¯

@Ипатьев убрал код с инъекцией

Большое спасибо, все заработало. Насчет sql буду изучать, как лучше написать, если есть возможность скиньте ссылку с информацией.

Ну и просто совет на будущее: функция должна делать что-то одно. ИЛИ получать данные из БД, ИЛИ форматировать их в определенный формат, ИЛИ выводить пользователю.
